# Guidelines in designing intuitive navigation

Tags: navigation

I have a site with about 6 loosely related items/pages where a user might want to navigate. I'm a bit stuck trying to design an intuitive layout.

At the moment I have a list of those 6 items on the left hand navigation, but it feels like the items don't belong together. I'm considering rather creating a landing page, that has a link to the relevant section together with a short description of what the section does.

Are there specific guidelines to creating such a landing page? Or how will you set out the navigation to a list of sections that are loosely related? Note that some of these sections could consist of multiple pages

Answer (score 1):

The only guideline I can suggest without much context is to conduct card sorting with users.

If I'm reading this correctly you want to create categories with short descriptions that will be displayed on the landing page instead of having a left nav on the landing page.

Without context it sounds like a good plan. It sounds like your six items are somewhat very different from one another, but some can still be grouped together.

Comment: Thanks, think that's exactly the word I was looking for "Card navigation".